# What is the role of "all" in phrases such as "All gone!"

Tags: pronouns, intensifiers

This evening one of my cats, during crazy time, bashed her way at a gallop into the kitchen, her tail an absolute bottle brush. "Oh, Bársony!" I said, "what's the matter? Your tail is all big!"

Then I started to wonder: What did I just say?

The phrase of encouragement and approval when a child has cleaned her plate -- "Irene, good for you! Your egg is all gone!"

The phrase of exhaustion, completion -- I'm all in.  It's all over, it's all done.

And then, Bársony's tail.

If someone can point me toward a discussion of "all", standing alone rather than with "of", as an intensifier (or of why it ISN'T an intensifier), I shall be grateful.

Comment: It's fine, and Bársony sounds like a lovely cat.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "all big", you are using "all" as an adverb. In this use, it is typical of less formal English. It is sometimes casually as a general intensifier.

The adverbial use of "all" in the phrase "all gone" is standard English, and means "completely".  And just like "completely" it does tend to intensify the sense of the adjective that it is modifying.

It is quite common that word can shift between pronoun, determiner and adverb, according to use, as English doesn't have a grammatical marker of these word-classes and the type of word is determined by syntax.